# Telerik OpenAccess generating the same query for every function call

Tags: c#, sql, telerik, repository-pattern, openaccess

I'm using a Generic Repository like pattern to fetch data. There are 100+ entities so creating a separate repository for each is not really an option.  here are a few functions from the same class:

```
    public int Count(Func<TEntity, bool> x=null)
    {
        return x == null ?
            mgr.CTX.GetAll<TEntity>().Count() :
            mgr.CTX.GetAll<TEntity>().Where(x).Count();
    }

    public TEntity One(Func<TEntity, bool> x)
    {
        return mgr.CTX.GetAll<TEntity>().Where(x).Take(1).FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public IQueryable<TEntity> All(Func<TEntity, bool> x=null)
    {
        return x == null ?
            mgr.CTX.GetAll<TEntity>() :
            mgr.CTX.GetAll<TEntity>().Where(x).AsQueryable<TEntity>();
    }
```

The problem is no matter which function is call, the Sql profiler shows the same

**Select [columns] from [table]**

I suppose when using Take(1) or Count() or Where() the query should be made accordingly using **Count()**, **Top** or **Where** clauses of **Select** but these functions have absolutely no effects on query generation. Apparently, every operation seems to be performed in memory after fetching all the data from server.

Guide me if there is something wrong with the way I'm accessing it or this is the normal behavior of telerik?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are victim of a subtle difference between definitions of LINQ extension method - in-memory ones use `Func<>` while SQL-bound use `Expression<>` as parameter type.
My suggestion is to change `All(Func<TEntity, bool> x=null)` to `All(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> x=null)`

Comment: you were so right! I really didn't know the difference. Now telerik OA is generating correct statements. and is really fast off course :P  thanks, any good resource to learn about expressions?